# Do servlet share same servletoutputstream object?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-3.0

I have one doubt in my mind.I have project which was running successfully before.But On sudden I have  faced one issue given below

```
java.lang.InternalError: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.text.BreakIterator.createBreakInstance(BreakIterator.java:596)
at java.text.BreakIterator.getBreakInstance(BreakIterator.java:541)
at java.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance(BreakIterator.java:468)
at java.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance(BreakIterator.java:455)
at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getBreakLocation(Utilities.java:427)
```

I was getting error in my jasper report when I was sending outputstream in response

I wanna know that
 1 Is tomcat share common servletOutputStream for one application?
 2 Is tomcat share one ServletOutputStream for one servlet ?
 3 As per my knowledge container create new ServletOutputStream for every response.

Please tell me which one is correct.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServletOutputStream is created for and associated with every single ServletResponse (which in turn is associated with a single request).

It is not shared with other requests.

Does this error always happen? Are just sometimes? Do you actually get an error in your browser window?

Otherwise, you may just be seeing the connection being interrupted (for example when the browser window is closed before the report generation is done).

Comment: Thanks for the reply the error is appearing on window.When I start the server it has gone.and Now I am not facing the same issue.